# How to disable options from mat-select based on option selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select

I was working on a project involving mat-select. I have two mat-selects,there I want to do two things:

1. When I select 'all' option in either of the mat-selects all the other options should get disabled.
2. When I select an option in one mat-select,that option needs to get disabled in the other mat-select
   This is the stackblitz link of the [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kucm4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Thanks in advance, for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in you second optiongroup

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of testList" [label]="group.displayName">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let num of group.pokemon; let i = index"
  [value]="num"
  disabled="{{ include.includes(num) || include.includes('all') }}"
  >
    {{ num }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! Made it so simple. I was thinking about using RxJS for this, but you did it simply using disabled.

Comment: @user18067747 but this solution will also disable option 'all' which cannot be unchecked again

Comment: @shashanksharma Yeah I too came across that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with above solution is if somebody select all all other option including both "all' option will be disabled. You can also change your data something like this to achieve your second requirement.

```
{
    name: 'Bulbasaur',
    value: 'Bulbasaur',
    selectedByA: false,
    selectedByB: true,
 },
```

and in html:

```
[disabled]="anyFunction(index, value)"
```

and now we can write our logic here:

```
isDisabled(index, value) {
    if (value.name != 'all') {
      if (index === 1) {                              // mat-select-one
        return value.selectedByB || this.allSelected; // return true if either all or selected by mat-select-B
      } else {                                        // mat-select-two
        return value.selectedByA || this.allSelected; // return true if either all or selected by mat-select-A
      }
    } else {
      return false; // in case of Option 'all' return always false
    }

  }
```

I have edited your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-183vcm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: The data cannot be changed. The data will come from API, that array of object was just to recreate how the data will look like.
Isn't there any other way?

Comment: you can save data from api after refectoring/mofying by using map().